# Sql query causing my computer to run out of memory

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a replication server with 24 GB RAM that is offline for maintenance at the moment. We running SQL Server 2014.

I have two databases that I want to find out how many records we have that are matching from 1 to the other.

```
Database 1 Name: Clients_Records.(Table).Retail_BASE
Database 2 Name: Clients_Documents.(Table).Documents
```

to match the records I'm using ID_Number for the is unique in each table and bring the other necessary fields in.

The below script runs for a few minutes and then times out with 'Run out of memory error'.

```
select [Clients_Records].[dbo].[Retail_BASE].CLIENT_CODE,
[Clients_Records].[dbo].[Retail_BASE].ID_NUMBER,
[Clients_Documents].[dbo].[Documents].CBAF8917 AS Document_Type
from [Clients_Records].[dbo].[Retail_BASE],
[Clients_Documents].[dbo].[Documents]
where [Clients_Records].[dbo].[Retail_BASE].ID_NUMBER = [Clients_Documents].[dbo].[Documents].B61DDE99
```

My result should look something like this.

```
CLIENT_CODE  ID_NUMBER  Document_Type
1234          111111       Contract
1234          111111       Agreement 
1234          111111       ID_Document
1235          111112       Contract
1235          111112       Agreement
1236          111113       Agreement
1237          111114       Contract
1237          111114       Agreement 
1239          111115       ID_Document
1240          111116       ID_Document
```

Please help with some guidance on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try a JOIN between the tables rather than using a WHERE clause.  I am reasonably certain that the optimizations used are going to be different, and this may benefit the query.

```
 select [Clients_Records].[dbo].[Retail_BASE].CLIENT_CODE,
        [Clients_Records].[dbo].[Retail_BASE].ID_NUMBER,
        [Clients_Documents].[dbo].[Documents].CBAF8917 AS Document_Type
 from   [Clients_Records].[dbo].[Retail_BASE]
     join [Clients_Documents].[dbo].[Documents]
         ON   [Clients_Records].[dbo].[Retail_BASE].ID_NUMBER = 
              [Clients_Documents].[dbo].[Documents].B61DDE99
```

I'm not 100% sure, but I think when you use the `Table1, Table2` syntax and filter with a WHERE clause, it joins every record in `Table1` to every record in `Table2`, and then filters out the non-matches.  That's going to need a lot of memory.  This is especially true of either `ID_NUMBER` or `B61DDE99` are non-indexed and the optimizer has to do a table scan.

ETA:  You indicated in your comment that you wanted only one document type returned per combination of `CLIENT_CODE` and `ID_NUMBER`.  The following may work better for you in that case.

Note that I'm using a Common Table Expresion (CTE) to filter down the contents of `Documents` to return just the `Document_Type` and `B61DDE99`.

```
 ;      
 WITH Unique_DocumentTypes
 AS (
     SELECT DISTINCT
            B61DDE99 as ID_NUMBER
        ,   CBAF8917 as Document_Type
     FROM   [Clients_Documents].[dbo].[Documents]
 )
 select rb.CLIENT_CODE,
        rb.ID_NUMBER,
        dt.Document_Type
 from   [Clients_Records].[dbo].[Retail_BASE] rb
     join Unique_DocumentTypes dt
         ON   rb.ID_NUMBER = dt.ID_NUMBER
```

Comment: HI @Ann L. thank you for your response, I still get system.out of memory Exception.

Comment: Looking at the data, there are more than 1 Documents type for each record. Like ID_Number 1111111 has 2 Contracts, three applications and 1 agreements, how would I filter that only one Document type for each documents is shown?

Comment: @user3906930  If all you want is the document type and no further information about the document, you could try using SELECT DISTINCT (the DISTINCT keyword after the SELECT keyword but before the first column name).  That will ensure that every record returned is unique.

Comment: @user3906930  I have added an additional suggested query.

Comment: thank you for the update, I have just executed the script, will let you know.

Comment: it gave me a result this time, thank you so much, however I do see there are still duplication in the document type? Thank you so much for the assistance so far....

Comment: @user3906930  I see.  I was implicitly assuming that `Client_BASE` had only one record per `CLIENT_CODE` and `ID_NUMBER`.  If it doesn't, you need another DISTINCT after the other SELECT (the lower one).

Comment: @user3906930 If you still have duplicates after that, you may have trailing blanks or some other irregularity in one of your columns, that prevent the records from being considered to have the same values.